# Finding it impossible to post simple ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am realy struggling with this and would apprecate any advice.

I have this field

```
<input id="scanInput" type="text" placeholder="SCAN" class="form-control" />
```

For which I would like to make an ajax call when the field changes, so I tried

```
<script>
$("#scanInput").change(function () {
    console.log('ye');

    $.getJSON("?handler=GetPartDetails", function (data) {
        //Do something with the data.
        console.log('yay?');
     }).fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
        var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
        console.log("Request Failed: " + err);
        });
});
</script>
```

Where my `PageModel` has this method

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GetPartDetails()
{
    return new JsonResult("hello");
}
```

and the url for the page in question is `/packing/package/{id}`

Now when I change the input value, I see `ye` on the console, and I can see that the network called `http://localhost:7601/Packing/Package/40?handler=GetPartDetails` (the correct URL I think?) with status code **200**

But My breakpoint in `GetPartDetails` never hits, and I don't see `yay?` in the console.

I also see this message from the `fail` handler:

> Request Failed: parsererror, SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 3 column 1 of the JSON data

But I'm not even passing any JSON data... why must it do this
I also tried this way :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "?handler=GetPartDetails",
    contentType : "application/json",
    dataType: "json"
})
```

but I get

> XML Parsing Error: no element found
>   Location: http://localhost:7601/Packing/Package/40?handler=GetPartDetails
>   Line Number 1, Column 1:

I also tried

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/?handler=Filter',
    data: {
        data: "input"
    },
    error: function (ts) { alert(ts.responseText) }
})
    .done(function (result) {
        console.log('done')
    }).fail(function (data) {
        console.log('fail')
    });
```

with Action

```
    public JsonResult OnGetFilter(string data)
    {
        return new JsonResult("result");
    }
```

but here I  see the result text in the console but my breakpoint never hits the action and there are no network errors..............
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `GetPartDetails` is a query string parameter or an action method name? Also `handler` is a query parameter name or what?

Comment: Please see the question - `GetPartDetails` is a method returning `IActionResult` in my `PageModel`...

Comment: what is `handler?=`?

Comment: I got it from here: http://www.talkingdotnet.com/handle-ajax-requests-in-asp-net-core-razor-pages/ - it should be the name of the method I think

Comment: I think the fix was just to include the controller name before handler

Comment: @KunalMukherjee I am using Razor Pages, but I have also tried including the full path ie `/Packaging/Package/40?handler=MethodNAme`

Comment: I don't know if this is the problem but it looks like your client code is doing a "GET" but your controller action has the HttpPost attribute?

Comment: @DaveG Please check my updated example (bottom of question) where I am posting data to a `post` method but still nothing is workig :(

Comment: @Bassie, can you update your question with the full code of your controller? It is easier to test.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me for posting this answer, I'd rather do this in the comment section, but I don't have the privilege yet.

Shouldn't your `PageModel` look like this ?

```js
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GetPartDetails() {
  return new JsonResult {
    Text = "text", Value = "value"
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesnt let me instantiate `JsonResult` like that - it just says TExt and Value dont exist

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I found a setup that works but I have no idea why..

PageModel

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult OnGetPart(string input)
    {
        var bellNumber = input.Split('_')[1];
        var partDetail = _context.Parts.FirstOrDefault(p => p.BellNumber == bellNumber);

        return new JsonResult(partDetail);
    }
```

Razor Page

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "/Packing/Package/" + @Model.Package.Id,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        input: barcode,
        handler: 'Part'
    },

    success: function (datas) {
        console.log('success');
        $('#partDescription').html(datas.description);
    }
});
```

Comment: It works because you have stumbled on the correct approach. It's worth spending a little time researching how handler methods work (https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/handler-methods), and how to use the jQuery ajax method (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Also, there is no place for the [HttpGet] or [HttpPost] attributes in Razor Pages. They belong to MVC and have no effect at all in Razor Pages.

Comment: @MikeBrind Thanks for the tip Mike - I'll check out those pages

Comment: `return new JsonResult("hello");` was most likely your problem, because "hello" is not a valid Json object.

Comment: @AdamVincent But then wouldn't the breakpoint still go to the method?

Comment: @AdamVincent the main error was that the AJAX call was not being made to the correct page. Then in the first example, the handler method name did not follow convention and would never get selected by the framework.

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, it is related with the Razor page handler. For [default handler routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions?view=aspnetcore-2.1#replace-the-default-page-app-model-provider).

> Handler methods for HTTP verbs ("unnamed" handler methods) follow a
>   convention: On[Async] (appending Async is optional but
>   recommended for async methods).

For your original post, to make it work with steps below:

- Change `GetPartDetails` to `OnGetPartDetails` which handler is `PartDetails` and http verb is `Get`.
- Remove `[HttpPost]` which already define the `Get` verb by `OnGet`.
- Client Request

  ```
   @section Scripts{ 
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#scanInput").change(function () {
              console.log('ye');

              $.getJSON("?handler=PartDetails", function (data) {
                  //Do something with the data.
                  console.log('yay?');
              }).fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
                  var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
                  console.log("Request Failed: " + err);
              });
          });
      });
  </script>
  }
  ```

You also could custom above rule by follow the above link to replace the default page app model provider